# put result of mySQL query into a different table

Tags: mysql

What I need to accomplish:

In Table 1 (table_original)
I need to take the last entry on the recent row, and take each column and process a SUM for each column.

Once this sum is carried out, the result for each column is then placed into a different table (table_result) under the same column header with avg  added to the end of the name.

I am able to take the columns  and complete the sum on the last entry into the database, 
Once I have the result I am unable to then send that to the other table to be stored, all within the same script.

The result should over write the existing sum in the column in second table (result).
Here is what I have tried.

```
INSERT INTO table_result(columnoneavg, columntwoavg, columnteavg)
SELECT 
columnone,
SUM(columnone / 147707 * 100000) columnoneavg,
columntwo,
SUM(columntwo / 56932* 100000) columntwoavg,
columnthree,
SUM(columnthree / 542868 * 100000) columnthreeavg
FROM
table_original
GROUP BY columnone
ORDER BY columnoneavg DESC
```

The above will give me the correct result, 
Now my issue is how can I then automatically put the result for each column into the second table to be stored, also the result should override the existing data for that column. 
I do get error INSERT is not valid in this position, but can not work out how to do this, and I can not find tutorials on how this can be done.

Comment: update your question add a proper data sample and the expected  result  ..

Comment: Look into triggers.

Comment: And when doing Covid infection rate calculations, store the county populations in a separate table.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all help. I am able to run the query and place into new table using this query

```
INSERT INTO `table_two` ( `sales1`, `sales2`, `sales3`) 
SELECT sum(sales1 / 56932 * 100000) sales1,sum(sales2 / 76176 * 100000) sales2,sum(sales3 / 118817 * 100000) sales3
FROM `table_one` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

However, the  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 does not take just the last entry from table_one, it is taking all data from this table, so onto that issue now.

Thanks again.